# In a Ring $R$, why does $(-1) \cdot a = a \cdot (-1)$ $\forall a \in R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Question is in the title. It came up while I was trying to show something else, and I realised I just assumed it was true.

Comment: Prove they are both equal to $-a$.

Comment: How? I thought -a was just another way or writing (-1)a? And how would you show that a(-1) = (-1)a?

Comment: No, $-a$ is the group-theoretic additive inverse of $a$ and has nothing to do with the multiplication (until, of course, you also prove that it coincides with $(-1)a$).

Comment: Oh of course. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(-1).a+a=(-1).a+(1)a.=(1-1).a=0$.

$a(-1)+a=a(-1)+a(1)=a(-1+1)=0$, by the unicity of the opposite, $(-1)a=a(-1)=-a$.

Comment: I took the liberty to correct what was seemingly a typo: $a(-1)a$ instead of $a(-1)$.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, $-1$ has the property $1+(-1)=(-1)+1=0$.  Also, $0+0=0$.
Therefore,
$$a\cdot 0 = a\cdot (0+0)=a\cdot 0+a\cdot 0\implies a\cdot 0=0$$
and
$$a+a\cdot(-1)=a\cdot 1+a\cdot(-1)= a\dot(1+(-1)) =a\cdot 0=0=a+(-a)\implies a\cdot(-1)=-a$$